# Create a reference inside a reStructuredText CSV table

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have a CSV table like this

```
.. csv-table::
   :header: Name, BrowseName, DataType, Description
   :widths: 16,16,16,52

   "Enabled", "Enabled", "Boolean", "Alarm can..."
```

and I would like to create a reference to a row in the HTML output. I tried to put `.. _reference:` to every place in the table, but either I have a compile error or an empty cell. I tried also to use a reST substitution definition, but without success.

Do you know if there is a way to add such a reference in that kind of table or references work only within grid tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert arbitrary reST in your CSV, similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54759554/2214933).  The alignment is tricky, so I recommend indenting everything uniformly by 4 spaces.  The label is inserted in the second row and the `:ref:` directive must be given both a title and the label, per Sphinx's documentation on the [`:ref:` role](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#ref-role).

```
:ref:`link to hello <mylabel>`

.. csv-table:: Test csv-table with multi-paragraph
    :header: "a", "b", "c"

    Cat,"Chunk that is updated periodically via copy-and-paste.

    Line #2, #3, etc", "Kitten"
    Dog,".. _mylabel:

    Hello", "Puppy"
    Walrus,"#.  List Item 1
    #.  List Item 2
    #.  List Item 3", "Pup"
```